# Mockito:Java - Unfinished stubbing detection

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit4

I have been working with Mockito and have run into this error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at       com.rbc.rewards.catalogue.service.B2SServicesTest.getProductList_Success(B2SServ icesTest.java:52)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
  when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
  when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
  doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
  1. missing thenReturn()
  2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
  3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

I have read in two posts on Stack Overflow about this issue but they do not go into full detail. I believe it has something to do with **nesting mocks inside a mocking** (from what I read). However I do not see or fully understand by the small snippets people have posted.

**My test class is as followed (leaving out unnecessary code):**

```
// Mock:  uses Java Reflection in order to create mock objects of each class
@Mock
private Scrapes scrapeS;
@Mock
private SsoS ssoS;
@Mock
private BScrape bScrape;

//@InjectMocks annotation is used to create and inject the mock object
@Mock
private BService bService;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

// Testing:
@Test
public void getProductList_Success() throws Exception{

        when(BService.getProductList("cookie", "6753"))
                .thenReturn(
                scrapeS.scrapePost(new String(),
                        new String(),
                        new HashMap<>(),
                        new bService()));
}
```

Method I need to call:

```
public List<prodItem> getProdList(String raw_cookie, String catId) throws Exception {
    String url = ssoSetting.getUrls().BProductList();
    String post = "url" + catId +"url";
    BScrape scraper = new BScrape ();
    Map<String, String> postRequest = new HashMap();
    postRequest.put("searchRequestParams", post);
    return scrapeS.scrapePost(url, raw_cookie, postRequest, scraper);
}
```

I am also using resources from [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_junit_integration.htm).

It is happening within the @test method and I believe this mocking inside mocking is because I am using it wrong I am assuming.

**After Implementation from Answer (working):**

```
@Mock
private SSetting sSetting = new SSetting ();
// Mock:  uses Java Reflection in order to create mock objects and is injected into InjectMocks
@Mock
private ProdItem productItem = new ProdItem ();
@Mock
private sService scrapeService = new sService ();
@Mock
private BScrape bScrape ;

//@InjectMocks annotation is used to create and inject the mock object
@InjectMocks
private BService bService = new BService ();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

// Testing:
@Test
public void getProductList_Success() throws Exception{

    List<ProductItem> retList = new ArrayList<>();
    retList.add(new ProductItem());
    retList.add(new ProductItem());

    //try{
    when(b2SServices.getProductList("cookie", "6753")).thenCallRealMethod();

    //test the add functionality
    when(BService .getProdList("cookie", "6753")).thenReturn(retList);


    }catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the third case:

> 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before
>   'thenReturn' instruction if completed

This happens because thenReturn calls method from another mock `scrapeS.scrapePost` It is hard to say exactly how to fix this because I would need more implementation details but try building the return object before `when` and it shouldn't be the return from another mock. There is a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319364/1121883

Here is a small example. You code is similar to `play` test. In then return you should provide an object instead of the call on the mock like in `fix` test.

```
@Test
public void play(){
    A a = mock(A.class);
    B b = mock(B.class);
    when(a.a("input")).thenReturn(b.b("input"));
}

@Test
public void fix(){
    A a = mock(A.class);
    B b = mock(B.class);
    String returnString = "b";
    when(a.a("input")).thenReturn(returnString);
}

static class A{
    String a(String in){
        return "a";
    }
} 

static class B{
    String b(String in){
        return "b";
    }
}
```

Your code should be something like:

```
    List<prodItem> retList = new ArrayList<>();
    retList.add(new ProdItem());
    retList.add(new ProdItem());
    when(bService.getProductList("cookie", "6753")).thenReturn(retList);
```

Comment: Sorry I do not fully understand? Can you go into a bit more detail with an example? Thanks so much

Comment: I think you and SpaceTrucker are close, I think i am doing it wrong. I added the method for which I am using for the test. Did not show Url so its a dummy url.

Comment: I appreciate the help by the way

Comment: @L1ghtk3ira I think your getProdList or getProductList (since the name is different) is a static method since you didn't call it on bService instance. You did not post the full code and this is hard to speculate what you are doing

Comment: if this is the case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods you will also need power mockito

Answer (score 1):

The (a bit simplified) evaluation order of your code

```
when(bService.getProductList("cookie", "6753"))
                .thenReturn(
                scrapeS.scrapePost(new String(),
                        new String(),
                        new HashMap<>(),
                        new bService()));
```

is first:

```
bService.getProductList("cookie", "6753")
```

second

```
when(/*...*/)
```

third

```
scrapeS.scrapePost(new String(),
                        new String(),
                        new HashMap<>(),
                        new bService())
```

.

So while trying to mock `bService` you use mock `scrapeS`.

Note that this doesn't make sense at all. Basically you are currently trying to give `bService.getProductList` an implementation which should use `scrapeS`. But `bService` is a mock and therefore has no implementaion.

If you want that the invocations of `bService` and `scrapeS` return the same object then store that object into a local variable and use that local variable in the `thenReturn` clause of both methods.

```
Object returnValue = /*whatever the return value is*/
when(bService.getProductList("cookie", "6753")).thenReturn(returnValue);
when(scrapeS.scrapePost(new String(), new String(), new HashMap<>(), new bService())).thenReturn(returnValue);
```

Comment: I think you and user1121883 are close, I think i am doing it wrong. I added the method for which I am using for the test. Did not show Url so its a dummy url.

Comment: I think I was using it wrong I only want to use the one method. So I think I only need this in yours : when(bService.getProductList("cookie", "6753")).thenReturn(returnValue);

Comment: Taking out my try catch it fails here: String url = ssoSetting.getUrls().BProductList();

Comment: You seem to not have injected the mock of `BService ` to the instance under test. However if your original question has been answered consider accepting an answer. You may ask a new question, if you are not able to solve your new problem after you have done some research on your own.

Comment: Very true I got off topic at the end. I marked user1121883 as it is more in dept and his last code solved the implementation. I am also giving you an up vote because I believe showing the steps as you did will help some people see the key order in case they are reviewing their code incorrectly.