# Getting UnfinishedStubbingException while mocking void method

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

Trying mock void method using JUnit4 then getting below exception

Below is the class definition

```
@Mock
private TestService service;

@Mock
private DatabaseService mockDatabase;

@Before
public void setUpMock() throws Exception {

    LOGGER.info("########### Moke setUp started ###########");

    conn = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    LOGGER.info("########### Moke setUp completed ###########");
}


@Test
public void testSuccess() {
    try {
        
        when(mockDatabase.getDBConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(service).deleteKeyInfo(mockDatabase.getDBConnection(), userBn, 1, "1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("### testDeviceIdNull ### Failed with following error: " + getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

But getting below exception

```
java.lang.AssertionError: ### Failed with following error: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:


E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

Below is the void method

```
public void deleteKeyInfo(Connection conn, UserBn userBn, Integer smId, String dId) throws Exception {
    // Deleting key
        
}
```

Comment: I haven't used Mockito in a while, but I believe the current preferred style is `when(service.deleteKeyInfo()).doNothing()`. (Also, I believe the `service.delete` should all be inside the `when`.)

Comment: For the root cause of the error, we need more context: what is `service` (mock or spy) `doNothing()` is default action for void methods for mocks. dropping the problematic line will help if `service` is a mock. what is `mockDatabase`? How you specified behaviour of `mockDatabase.getDBConnection()`?

Comment: @Lesiak Updated the question with more info

Answer (score 3):

You're nesting mocking inside of mocking. You're calling getDBConnection(), which does some mocking, before you've finished the mocking for service.

Mockito doesn't like it when you do this.

Replace:

```
try {
        
        when(mockDatabase.getDBConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(service).deleteKeyInfo(mockDatabase.getDBConnection(), userBn, 1, "1");
    }
```

with:

```
try {
        
        when(mockDatabase.getDBConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
        some_variable_name =  mockDatabase.getDBConnection();         
        Mockito.doNothing().when(service).deleteKeyInfo(some_variable_name, userBn, 1, "1");
    }
```

Please check this : [Unfinished Stubbing Detected in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318569/unfinished-stubbing-detected-in-mockito) for more information

Comment: 2 minor comments: 1. You don't need a temporary variable, just use conn. 2 As an alternative, Mockito.doNothing is the default for void methods, the entire call can be dropped.