# Register Mock Bean during Integration Testing for SpEL Bean Reference

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing

I am getting the following error while running the test from my spring-boot app. I am using version= 2.3.3.RELEASE of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and version=2.2.0 of `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` for integration testing.

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1058E: A problem occurred when trying to resolve bean 'gameServiceImpl':'Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory'

    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.BeanReference.getValueInternal(BeanReference.java:59)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:308)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.getCollection(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation.getCollectionName(MappingMongoEntityInformation.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.save(Unknown Source)
    at eatigo.com.webscraper.service.GameServiceImplTest.testSavingSingleEntity(GameServiceImplTest.java:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory
    at org.springframework.context.expression.BeanFactoryResolver.resolve(BeanFactoryResolver.java:54)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.BeanReference.getValueInternal(BeanReference.java:55)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'gameServiceImpl' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.BeanFactoryResolver.resolve(BeanFactoryResolver.java:51)
    ... 90 more
```

Below is my simple code implementations

I underdtand that the problem lies in this statement `@Document(collection = "#{@gameServiceImpl.getCollectionName()}")` because during testing, the SPEL can't find any bean with name='gameServiceImpl' because it has been mocked during testing.

1. Is there a way to inject a mock bean in the spring container registry for it to be recognized by SPEL?
2. Is it possible to replace and inject value in the class annotation here `@Document(collection = "replace and inject value here")` during the initialization of entity class e.g `Game game= new Game();`

Entity

```
@Document(collection = "#{@gameServiceImpl.getCollectionName()}")
public class Game {
    @Id
    private int gameId;
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends MongoRepository<Game, String> {
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class GameServiceImpl implements GameService {

    private GameRepository gameRepository;
    private String collectionName;

    @Autowired
    public GameServiceImpl(GameRepository gameRepository){
        this.gameRepository = gameRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
        return collectionName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
    }

    public Game save(Game game){
        return gameRepository.save(game);
    }
}
```

Test

```
ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MainApplication.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DataMongoTest
public class GameServiceImplTest {

    @Mock(name = "gameServiceImpl")
    private GameServiceImpl gameServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private GameRepository gameRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSavingGame(){
        Game game= new Game();

        String collectionName = "testing";
        gameServiceImpl.setCollectionName(collectionName);
        when(gameServiceImpl.save(game)).thenReturn(gameRepository.save(game));
        when(gameServiceImpl.getCollectionName()).thenReturn(collectionName);

        Game result = gameServiceImpl.save(game);

        assertThat(result, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(mongoTemplate.collectionExists(collectionName), is(true));
        assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(Game.class, collectionName).size(), equalTo(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `@Mock` where you should be using `@MockBean`. Your test is also weird you either run an `@SpringBootTest` or an `@DataMongoTest` but not both. One is a full integration test, the other just a slice.

Comment: I have a similar problem but did not resolved. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259736/how-do-i-unit-test-spring-security-preauthorize-custom-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259736/how-do-i-unit-test-spring-security-preauthorize-custom-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @M. Deinum direction and some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319364/6434650), I was able to achieve results with the following modifications.

Test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DataMongoTest
public class GameServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean(name = "gameServiceImpl")
    public GameServiceImpl gameServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private GameRepository gameRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testSavingSingleEntity(){
        Game game = new Game();

        String collectionName = "testingCollection";
        gameServiceImpl.setCollectionName(collectionName);
        when(gameServiceImpl.getCollectionName()).thenReturn(collectionName);

        Game result = gameRepository.save(game);
        when(gameServiceImpl.save(game)).thenReturn(result);

        assertThat(gameServiceImpl.save(game), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(mongoTemplate.collectionExists(collectionName), is(true));
        assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(Game.class, collectionName).size(), equalTo(1));
    }
}
```