# Intermittent Unfinished stubbing detected here failure from mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, testng

I have a unit test that fails only some of the time with this error:

```
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.example.testHandlePublish(MyTestClass.java:78)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

The test is below. There are various questions here on this particular error, with the main cause seeming to be nested mocking (Hint 3 above):

[Unfinished Stubbing Detected in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318569/unfinished-stubbing-detected-in-mockito)

but I don't think this is the case here, given that the test passes most of the time?

```
@Test
public void testHandlePublish()
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    BlockingQueue<Event<QueueConsumer>> consumerEvents = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    BlockingQueue<Event<WorkerPublisher>> publisherEvents = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Channel channel = Mockito.mock(Channel.class);
    WorkerConfirmListener listener = Mockito.mock(WorkerConfirmListener.class);
    WorkerPublisher impl = new WorkerPublisherImpl(channel, metrics, consumerEvents, listener);
    EventPoller<WorkerPublisher> publisher = new EventPoller<>(2, publisherEvents, impl);
    Thread t = new Thread(publisher);
    t.start();
    publisherEvents.add(new WorkerPublishQueueEvent(data, "testQueue", taskInformation));
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Answer<Void> a = invocationOnMock -> {
        latch.countDown();
        return null;
    };
    Mockito.doAnswer(a).when(channel).basicPublish(Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq("testQueue"), Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq(data));
    latch.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    publisher.shutdown();
    Assert.assertEquals(0, publisherEvents.size());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, consumerEvents.size());
}
```

The test is failing on this line:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(a).when(channel).basicPublish(Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq("testQueue"), Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq(data));
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to start running your test (by starting your publisher thread) before you've finished setting up your mocks?

Comment: @tgdavie Probably not, I could move the `Mockito.doAnswer` above the `t.start()`. Do you suspect that may be why this test fails randomly? Would this account for the mockito error message I am seeing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may make the test more consistent.